# What is the primary key in such a table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am making a database for the employees.
I have created a table for employees information and set an employee id as a primary key. 
I used that primary key in most of the tables as a foreign key.
the problem is I can't find a primary key for some tables except the foreign key which is is the employee id.
Here is an example:
Salary table
columns:

Basic_salary
Housing_allowance
Transfer_allowance
Status
Employee_id (Foreign key)

another example:
Skills table

Columns:

employee_id (foreign key)
Skill

The only unique column here is the employee id.
Can I use it as primary key?

Comment: Do you expect to have multiple entries for an employee in each table? People usually just have one *current* salary, but if your status is used to track prior salary then you could have multiple entries. Likewise for the skills, I expect you could easily have more then one per employee. If so, Employee Id alone won't be unique. Are you averse to adding an Id column or making a primary key over two existing columns?

Comment: No, I am making the table for current salary only if the salary is changed then the table will be updated without repeating the employee id

Comment: but for the skill table the employee id will be entered more than once

Answer (score 0):

In a word - yes. There's nothing preventing you having a primary key that's also a foreign key to another table. `Id` is a great primary key for this table.

Answer (score 0):

From your fields in that table the "status employee_id" is already a foreign key, so you can't use it as a primary key. If that table is for Employees, then yes Employee_ID would definitely be the primary key